# How can I pass custom data to Stripe webhook?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am creating and processing a stripe payment like this:

```js
    // Create payment intent
    const { data } = await axios.post('/api/payments/get-payment-intent', { slug: post.slug })

    // Use payment intent to charge the card
    const result = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(data.paymentIntentSecert, {
      payment_method: {
        card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
      },
    })
```

To be able to fulfill the order, I need to be able to pass some data (`id` of the product and `username` of the buyer) to the webhook that gets executed after the payment has been successfully completed (`payment_intent.succeeded` event).

How can I do that?

I've tried adding a `metadata` key to the `confirmCardPayment()` like this:

```js
    const result = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(data.paymentIntentSecert, {
      payment_method: {
        card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
        metadata: {
          username: user.username,
          postId: post.id
        }
      },
    })
```

But the metadata doesn't show up on the object received by the webhook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to update the PaymentIntent metadata using [`confirmCardPayment()`](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment).

You would first want to pass the username and postId to your backend server.

Example

```
const { data } = await axios.post('/api/payments/get-payment-intent', { 
    username:user.username, 
    postId: post.Id 
});
```

And subsequently [create the PaymentIntent with the metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-metadata).

Node.js example to create a PaymentIntent

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: 2000,
  currency: 'usd',
  metadata: {
      username,
      postId
  },
});
```

Comment: How would you then access the metadata in the webhook? I'm trying to process a function based on a user name passed in the metadata. The user is currently in the metadata, but how do I access it in the webhook?

Comment: @GraphicsFactory I suggest you submit a new stackoverflow question. Without looking at your code and the response that you're receiving, it's not possible to troubleshoot/help.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it and posted the solution below.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it for stripe.checkout.sessions.create. Here is the code...

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
          line_items: [
            {
              price: 'price_example',
              quantity: 1,
            },
          ],
          mode: 'payment',
          success_url: `https://www.example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
          cancel_url: `https://www.example.com/?canceled=true`,
          automatic_tax: {enabled: true},
          metadata : {
            my_user: user,
            my_tokens: tokens,
          }
        });
```

To access the event data I did this in the webhook...

```
try {
...
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(buf.toString(), sig, webhookSecret);
}
```

then to get the metadata from event ...

```
  const gotTokens = event.data.object.metadata.my_tokens;
  const theUser = event.data.object.metadata.my_user;
```

Comment: This is helpful, but the metadata object within the event (constructEvent) coming into the webhooks route is empty despite having set the data in the  checkout session. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: I've updated the reply above to include the code I used in the webhook to get the event data.

Comment: Thank you @Graphics Factory - it turned out to be due to the metadata only coming through on certain event types. I had to attach it to the subscription (or payment_intent I believe) then it would come through certain event types in the webhook. I believe I ultimately used the 'invoice.succeeded' event type. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the metadata under the key `payment_intent_data` when creating the checkout session. This metadata will be attached by stripe on every webhook call.

```js
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      line_items: [
        {
            price: 'price_1234567890',
            quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      mode: 'payment',
      payment_intent_data:  {
          metadata: {
              userId: 123, // here you can set the metadata
          },
      },
      success_url: '',
      cancel_url: '',
    });
```